# html() strips script tags in fancybox (jQuery) ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, tags, fancybox

My issue is quite similar to these ones:

- [jquery html() strips out script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079179/jquery-html-strips-out-script-tags)
- [jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed)

But this is a particular case and none of them worked for me.
I am using the `fancybox` (1.3.4) jQuery plugin to display the result of an ajax call which returns an HTML string. The HTML string contains an ajax form with `jQuery` lines, which are not outputting because of the `html()` function. I tried replacing it by `innerHTML` (which is actually the same as `html()`) or replacing the tags by others and then updating it but nothing worked.
If you want to know exactly where this happens it's line `265` in the fancybox JS file.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Cheers,
Nicolas.

**EDIT:**
an example of the code retreived by ajax containing the `<script>` tag:

```
<div class="ddinline">
    <form id="form542612422" onsubmit="return false;" update="searchbtn" position="before" method="post" action="/Librariescategories/AJAXGetChildrenList" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $('#form542612422').bind('submit', function(){ $.ajax({async:true, type:'post', beforeSend:function(request) {$("#filter .ddinline").last().after('<img src="/img/loading.gif" id="catload" alt="" />');}, complete:function(request, json) {$('#searchbtn').before(request.responseText); $("#catload").remove(); createDropDown($("#filter .fulldrop").last());}, data:$('#form542612422').serialize(), url:'/Librariescategories/AJAXGetChildrenList'}) })
        //]]>
        </script>
        <select name="data[Librariescategories][id]" class="fulldrop" id="LibrariescategoriesId">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">select</option>
            <option value="1">3D Models</option>
            <option value="259">Imagery</option>
            <option value="362">Textures</option>
       </select>
       <div class="hide">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of the HTML code, with script, you retrieve by ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to add your script and html something separately. You can send the markup and script joined by a token over the wire. Split them up via javascript on the client. Then add the html into the fancybox element. The script may need to be added outside the fancybox element. Here is an example of how to add the html and script into the same element:

http://jsbin.com/otage3/2/edit

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Hi Bob, this is a great idea but actually I am using cakePHP and the JavaScript is automatically generated by the AJAX helper in the view, so I do not see any way of separating it from the HTML. Moreover, I cannot use a "standard" syntax for the generated code because the form id is automatically generated during the AJAX helper code. Cheers.

Comment: Or I can extract the JS code via a regexp and try to insert it somewhere else in the parent document. I'm not sure if it will be possible, but I'll give a try.

Comment: Your idea was the good one! I split my string into two: one with the regular HTML and the other one with the JS, then I insert the HTML and append the JS to the `fancybox-content` wrap in a `<script>` as you did in your example. Cheers!