# Loading ASPX page with Javascript intact, with a twist

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, get

I am writing a single page web application for Microsoft SharePoint.

I'd like to pull in content with `$.get()`, but I've run into a bit of a catch 22.

If I pull in the content like this:

```
function getLocalPage(url, callback) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var $page = $(data).filter('.tileContent').html();
        callback($page);
    });
}
```

I get the node I'm looking for, but my script tags have been stripped out.

If I pull in content like this:
(reference to: [jquery html() strips out script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079179/jquery-html-strips-out-script-tags) )

```
function getLocalPage(url, callback) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var dom = $(data);
        dom.filter('script').each(function(){
            $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
        });
        var $page = dom.filter('.tileContent');
        callback($page);
    });
}
```

The javascript embedded in SharePoint blows my page up, and seems to cause a full postback.

Is there any way to get only the node I would like, with the script tags intact?
Can't seem to have it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than the shorthand jQuery method `.get()`, try `.ajax()` with `dataType: 'html'`

The `.ajax()` documentation says of `dataType: 'html'` :

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

It also says :

> "If 'html' is specified, any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved data is executed before the HTML is returned as a string."

The emphasis here is on the word "before" meaning that the embedded JavaScript, when executed, cannot act *directly* on the HTML with which it is delivered (or a resulting DOM-fragment), though it can act directly on the existing DOM, prior to fragment insertion.

However, any **functions** included in the embedded JavaScript do indeed **become available** to act on the HTML/DOM-fragment and the DOM at large, if **called later**. The first opportunity to call such functions is in the `.ajax()` success handler (or chained `.done()` handler).

Unless extraordinary (and potentially messy) measures are taken, the success handler (or any functions called by it) will need prior "knowledge" of the names of any functions that are delivered in this way, otherwise (realistically) they will be uncallable.

I'm not sure about code delivered inside a `$(function() {...});` structure, which *may* execute when the current event thread has completed(?). If so, then it *could* potentially be made to act on the delivered HTML/DOM-fragment. By all means try.

With all that in mind, try the following approach, with appropriately phrased JavaScript in the response.

```
function getLocalPage(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            callback($(data).find('.tileContent'));
        }
    });
}
```

or better :

```
function getLocalPage(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(data) {
        callback($(data).find('.tileContent'));
    });
}
```

Notes:

- I changed `.filter()` to `.find()`, which seems more appropriate but you may need to change it back.
- Your final version may well have further `.ajax()` options.

Comment: Hey Beetroot! Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, $.find() returns an empty jQuery object, and .filter().html() still returns a string with the script tags missing. Might repost the question with a fiddler or something. This is a tough one.

Comment: Yes, the script tags are guaranteed to be missing. They will have been stripped out and their code executed as described. That's pretty well the point. I don't know whether `.find()` or `.filter()` is more appropriate without seeing the HTML or the callback - if neither works, then the selector or something else is wrong - possibly what is returned by the server.

Comment: Yeah. The goal here is to leave the script tags intact, because they are going to a hidden holding element, to be transffered later into a modal, and I need the script tags to execute on transfer. I have a workaround, but I'm not sure I feel good about it.

Comment: Wesley, I think you will find everything gets easier if you take on board my point about delivering function(s) rather than code which executes immediately.

Comment: And something you might like to consider is the use of one or more [jQuery Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/) objects to manage delivered functions.