# Could not insert script string from ajax response

Tags: php, html, ajax, response, string

[image: inserting script ajax response did not work]

On php, I have array which had 2 parts as following

```
array('threeRowHtml'=> '<HTML output string>',
'jsCode'=> '<script output string>'
)
```

I return that array for my ajax call. I parsed the response and I could take two of those strings. I would like insert them into my page and eval to execute the return js script. I could insert "threeRowsHtml" OK, but with 'jsCode' did not work.

```
$.ajax({
            url: postUrl,
            type: "post",
            beforeSend:function(){
                process.show(); // just my popup
            },
            success: function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                if(data.returnCode == 1){
                    //var jsCode = eval("(" + data.jsCode + ')');
                    console.log(data.jsCode); // print out OK
                    $('#rp_script').replaceWith(data.jsCode); // did not work
                    $('#rp_content').replaceWith(data.threeRowsHtml); // insert into page OK

                }
                else{
                    $('#rp_errors').replaceWith(data.errorHtml);
                }

                process.hide();
            }
        })
```

Here is the location for inserting the response

```
<div id="rp_content">

</div>

<div id="rp_actions">

</div>

<div id="rp_script">

</div>
<div id="rp_errors"></div>
```

The return script string's syntax was fine, because if it was wrong, it would notice me the JS error token.
The result is always empty string for "jsCode" and I don't know what wrong with it. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem. 
[jquery html() strips out script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079179/jquery-html-strips-out-script-tags)

Now I can print out the script into my page

```
$('#rp_script')[0].innerHTML = data.jsCode;
```

Of cause, I still use global.eval to execute my script.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, js code is processed THEN stripped from XHR response, you may test if your JS code is being interpretted by adding a `debugger;` line directly below the opening script tag. open your code inspector/dev tool/whatever to see if it stops at your explicit breakpoint.

See this for reference. It could be related [jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed)

Comment: I voted one for you since your answer gave me the reference for solution, but the script tag was stripped by html or replaceWith instead. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't like the response is properly escaped. There are unescaped " in the string.