# Script Execution after pushing into DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pushing HTML Code including `<script>` in a div, I am able to push inside the div successfully using
`innerHTML` but script is not executing.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    data: '',
    dataType: 'html',
    ContentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.ashx',
    success: function(result) {
        $("#div").attr('innerHTML', result));
        var arr = $("#divClaims").find('script'));
        for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
            eval(arr[n].html());
    }
});
```

Result looks like :

```
"<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Code for script....
</script>
<div id=''></div>"
```

I have searched in here but not able to get a working solution
The script is coming from the procedure so I just have to consume it.
I tried all Other questions available in here but no success. I am not vary good with javascript....

I have tried this as well:

```
function testCode(script1) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script[(script.innerText === undefined ? "textContent" : "innerText")] = script1;
        document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
    }
```

No luck!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery html() strips out script tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079179/jquery-html-strips-out-script-tags)

Comment: I am able to find the script here but it seems its not executing. It results in a blank page

Comment: jquery execute `<script>` tag when using html("<script></script>");

Comment: @RGraham `By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute code. `

Comment: so just use `$("#div").html(result);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: its not working as the result contains script tag in it.

Comment: Thanks, not sure where I got the idea it stripped them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the html code then use

```
$("#div").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically appending script tags mixed with html elements can be more tricky that initially thought (innerHTML will not work)

Usually, using

```
$('#target').html(html)
```

does a pretty good job.

jQuery specifically excludes `script`, `link` and `style` from the `innerHTML` code branch here : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/src/manipulation.js#L414

```
// See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value )

where
rnoInnerhtml = /<(?:script|style|link)/i,
```

You can look how jQuery handles the `script` case in the `domManip` function. see [domManip source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/src/manipulation.js#L465)

jQuery extracts the script tags and then evals them, with a special case regarding the `script.src` attribute.

This jsFiddle seems to be working for me : https://jsfiddle.net/sqz73pjg/ both for executing and inline script and loading an external script.