# Not posting any data to page in URL parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have 2 PHP files where I want to use the `$_POST` method to post data to page number 2 (`pageA.php` & `pageB.php` which are in the root directory)

Here is pageA.php:

```php
<?php

$userID = "123";
$userName = "Frank";

?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="mystyle/app/res/js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js">
</script>
    <script src="mystyle/app/res/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $userID;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="userName" value="<?php echo $userName;?>"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var userID = $('input[name="userID"]').val();
    var userName = $('input[name="userName"]').val(); 

    $('body').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pageB.php',
        data: {userID: userID, userName: userName},
        success: function() {
            alert(userID + userName);
            $('body').load('pageB.php');
            }

        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is pageB.php:

```php
<?php
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
echo "<script>alert('" . $userID . "');</script>";
?>
```

The error message I get originates from PHP and is the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: userID in C:\xampp\htdocs\pageB.php on line 2

What am I doing wrong so that no data is being posted to the second page? My `alert ();` in the AJAX request shows the right data.

Comment: You can remove the body.load() method, this is basically a second call. The actual error comes from the load() method since you do not pass any POST data with this call. So userID is undefined.

Comment: I know that it should be what you wrote but i read otherwise in a other stockoverflow post, however i tried both versions an neither works :/ @hallleron

Answer (score 4):

After your `ajax()` call completes, you immediately request `pageB.php` *again*, via `.load()`, with no parameters at all. Hence the error.

If you want to load the results of `pageB.php`, just do so using the results of the `ajax()` call:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
}
```

Comment: alright, interesting how no one could give me that answer in the others posts :/ however thanks! but the data is not being displayed back in the body tag with that .html(data); method/function :O I was putting a alert(); inside pageB but that alert never shows :/

Comment: Without seeing the actual contents of pageB, or a simplified example that demonstrates the problem, no way to know what's going on there. Consider adding another question to resolve *that* issue.

Comment: See [jQuery html strips out script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079179/jquery-html-strips-out-script-tags) for more on that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting `pageB.php` *twice*.  Once with the data, and then once *without* the data.  The first request is working without error, the *second* request is giving you the error.

Just remove the completely unnecessary second request:

```
$('body').load('pageB.php');
```