# Grab Html Tags from HTML Variable using get() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First:  I am new to javascript so please forgive me if my syntax is novice.

I have been trying to get data in HTML tags using get() in jquery.  But no matter how many different variations I try, it just won't work.  Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Below is the javascript I am using.

```
$.get('load.html', function(raw){
    var bodyHtml = $(raw).filter('body').html();
    var divHtml = $(raw).filter('div').html();
    var title = $(raw).filter('title').text();
    var tag = $(raw).filter('tag').html();
    $('#body').html(bodyHtml);
    $('#tag').html(tag); 
    $('#title').html(title);
    $('#result').html(divHtml);
    $('#raw').html(raw);
});
```

Below is the html on the load.html page.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title load.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>div 1<tag>divtag</tag></div>
<tag>tag</tag>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the results once page has run. index.html

```
<html><head>
<title>index.html</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  

$.get('load.html', function(raw){
    var bodyHtml = $(raw).filter('body').html();
    var divHtml = $(raw).filter('div').html();
    var title = $(raw).filter('title').text();
    var tag = $(raw).filter('tag').html();
    $('#body').html(bodyHtml);
    $('#tag').html(tag); 
    $('#title').html(title);
    $('#result').html(divHtml);
    $('#raw').html(raw);
});

</script> 
</head>

<body> 

<div id="title">title load.html</div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="result">div 1<tag>divtag</tag></div>
<div id="tag">tag</div>
<div id="raw">

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>title load.html</title>


      <div>div 1<tag>divtag</tag></div>
      <tag>tag</tag>


</div>


</body></html>
```

One thing to note. It looks like the  isn't sent back from jquery.  Also if there is multiple  on the page.  Shouldn't this script make it a array (example being )

Comment: Someone else seems to have figured out what causes this. But I can't figure out the correct way to integrate into my solution. Any ideas? [Here is the other stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed/2699905#2699905)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the results.  I thought it was the html() tag stripping the body, and head tags out of the variable.  When I would do a alert(raw) from a url it would show the full html page.  But then when I try and modify that variable, the tags () would disappear.  I then thought it was jquery.  So I tried a regular expression.  Sure enough I got the same exact results.  So I am only able to retrieve tags like title, divs, but not the body.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.get('load.html', function(raw){

        var matches = raw.match(/<title\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/gi);
        //var matches = matches[0].replace(/(<\/?[^>]+>)/gi, ''); // Strip HTML tags?

        alert(matches);

    }, "html");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `$.get()` call inside a "document ready" handler - at the moment the DOM elements you're trying to manipulate don't exist at the point you're making the call:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will make sure to add that into my practice.  However, the same result.  Someone else seems to have figured out what causes this.  But I can't figure out the correct way to integrate into my solution.  Any ideas?

[Here is the other stackoverflow post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed/2699905#2699905)