# evaluate script through jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone tell me why the following function might not be working.
The `get` call should return a mix of html and `<script>`. I'm trying to find the script element and then evaluate what is inside. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

```
function showRecaptcha()
{
alert("test1");
var file = "recapatchatest.php";
$("div#commentWindow").get("../commentfiles/" + file, function(data)
{
  var script = data.getElementsByTagName("script");
  $("div#commentWindow").html(eval(script));
});
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2699905

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct .get() method. You have to differenciate these two:

- [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (the one you're using) - retrieves a DOM element at the specified index from the matched elements in the jquery object.
- [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) ($.get()) - load data from the server using a HTTP GET

So you should obviously be using the second one.

*Be aware that the content of `data` will not be a DOM element on which you could call getElementByTagName, it is just a string of HTML data.*

---

If you are trying to load html into an existing element, you should consider using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which does exactly what you're after:

> .load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] ) Returns: jQuery
>
> **Description:** Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Comment: I use `.load` a lot - but when I do it this way the <script> in the page I'm calling does not evaluate.

Comment: I don't use that a lot to be honest, but for sure you're not using the correct get() method. If your page contains only scripts, turn to [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Answer (score 1):

Loading an HTML page via AJAX, parsing out the `<script>` tags, and `eval`ing them sounds like a bad idea.

When appended to the DOM, `<script>` tags will automatically run.  So, just append `data` to the DOM, and your scripts will run.

Or, put the scripts in their own files, and load 'em with `$.getScript`.

Also, `$("div#commentWindow").get` should be changed to just `$.get`.

```
$.get("../commentfiles/" + file, function(data)
```

Comment: ok, your suggestion is helpful - this way feels really complicated

Comment: @Jeff: To make things simple, I like to keep my scripts separate from my HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `$.get` instead of `$("div#commentWindow").get`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$("div#commentWindow").get("../commentfiles/" + file, function(data)
{
  var script = data.getElementsByTagName("script");
  $("div#commentWindow").html(eval(script));
});
```

with

```
$.get("../commentfiles/" + file, function(data){
  var script = data.getElementsByTagName("script");
  $("div#commentWindow").html(eval(script));
});
```

Your original code wasn't actually making an ajax request.

Additionally, to get the scripts, try this as the success handler:

```
var $content = $("#commentWindow");
$.get("../commentfiles/" + file, function(data){
    var html = data;
    html = html.replace(/<script/ig, "<div class='script'").replace(/<\/script/ig, "</div>");
    var html = $(html);
    var scripts = html.filter("div.script").add($(html).find("div.script")).detach();
    $content.html(html);
    scripts.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), s = document.createElement("script");
        if ($this.attr('src') != "") {
            s.src = $this.attr('src');
        } else {
            s.nodeValue = $this.text();
        }
        $content[0].appendChild(s);
    });
});
```

The above code has been updated based on comments and now correctly handles both script includes and inline script tags.

Comment: `data` is a string, and not a DOM Element.

Comment: @Rocket - Yes, that is why I used a regex to replace the elements and then placed the text in a `$(html)` to select the scripts (which I turned into div tags so that they wouldn't execute or be removed by jquery). For comparison, History.js uses a very similar method.

Comment: Thanks for the above - but how the script know where to put the executed script -- ie $("div#commentWindow")

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `get` method passes a string to the callback function. `data.getElementsByTagName` doesn't work because `getElementsByTagName` is not a valid method for an instance of the `String` object.

I'm not sure why you use the `eval` method at all. That method is for JavaScript code, and even ignoring that your assignment to the `script` variable is flawed your intent was to invoke `eval` on an array of HTML `SCRIPT` elements.

The final issue is that jQuery's `html` method ignores `SCRIPT` tags in any string of HTML markup that you pass to it.

If you want to add `SCRIPT` tags to the DOM you're going to need to use plain ol' vanilla JavaScript and bypass jQuery altogether.