# inline script loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, inline, product

I am working with the 360 product spin jquery plugin:
[Link to 360-javascriptviewer](http://www.360-javascriptviewer.com/learning-centre/free-version.html)

This is activated with the following inline script at the bottom of the html and works fine.

```
function test () {
    mloaderx = new loader(
    {
    tag:'product_image_x',
    frames:36,
    zoom:false
    });
}
test();
```

The problem I am having is when this content is loaded in to another page via ajax. The inline script does not pull through, even when I include it on the other page as well.

I have included the whole code below but the only part it concerns is the ajax call.

```
// NOTES: This script will load content into a placeholder div with a nice scroll down effect.

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".loadContent").click(function (event) {

        // show loading div
        showLoading();
        var clickedElement = jQuery(this);

        // stop initial jump to anchor.
        event.preventDefault();

        var contentURL = clickedElement.attr("href");

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: contentURL + "?" + new Date().toUTCString(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (strData) {
                populateContent(strData);
            },
            complete: function () {
                hideLoading();
                scrollToContent();

            }

        });
    });
});

function showLoading() {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeIn(100);
    jQuery("#loaded_content").slideUp(800);
}

function hideLoading() {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeOut(100);
    //jQuery(".to_top").show();
}

function populateContent(strData) {
    jQuery("#loaded_content").html(jQuery(strData).find("#loadarea").html());
    $('.media_main_content .article p:first').wrapFirstLetter();
}

function scrollToContent() {
    $("#subnav_content").toggle(800, function() {
        jQuery("#loaded_content").slideDown(800);
        jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(".ca_nav_holder").offset().top}, 800, function() {
            jQuery("#toggle_subnav span").fadeTo(700, 0.1).fadeTo(700, 1);
        });
    });
}
```

Has anyone any advice they could give? I've been banging my head against a brick all for two days now trying to figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed

Comment: I have looked at the solution for the other question however I cannot get it to work with what I require.  Using the example for the other question I can call an alert from within the test function and then the content is loaded OK.  However, when I replace the alert with mloaderx = new loader etc the content will not load in.