# How to emulate $(window).load()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax query, which returns html code containing a lot of `$(window).load()` functions. I need to call all of these functions again.

I would like to do so by invoking the `$(window).load()`method again.
How do i trigger it manually from my code?

Comment: Please find my answer below, accidentaly i put comment

Comment: You could just trigger the load your self: `$(window).load(handler).trigger('load')` although I guess it would be a better idea to change the script you are receiving thru AJAX (in case you can).

Comment: Script blocks loaded by `$.ajax` are not executed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed for a workaround

Comment: This question solved my problem, I was really in need to run javascript after calling content through ajax. Thanks

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("load"));`

Answer (score 10):

You could trigger

```
$(window).trigger( 'load' );
```

I personally advise against this solution. It is a bad practice. You should find another solution because the window load event could be tied to other several and different callbacks you don't know.

Comment: thank u! I understand that is a bad way, but i need a fast solution, to have some time to write correct working solution. based on events

Comment: this won't work - the scripts aren't executed when the HTML is loaded so the handlers don't get registered.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is solve you problem. test.js is that name your java script file .

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce simple message bus to achieve this goal. Initially you could rely on window's load event, later you could create a notifier module to inform all interested modules (code) that something happened.