# Javascript function response in Jquery not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that using ajax to post the comment to video_comment.php then show up the comment live on video page.

This is my jquery code:

```
$("input[id*='post_video_playallcomment_']").livequery('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    var video_msg   = $("#post_message");
    var input_id    = $(this).attr('id');
    var id_split    = input_id.split('_');
    var video_id    = id_split[3];                    
    var comment     = $("textarea[id='video_comment']").val();
    var response_messages = '#video_response';        

    if ( comment == '' ) {
        video_msg.fadeIn();
        return false;
    }

    video_msg.hide();
    user_posting(response_messages, '<?php echo $lang['600']; ?>', 1);
    reset_chars_counter();
    $.post(base_url + '/video_comment.php', { video_id: video_id, comment: comment },
    function(response) {
        if ( response.msg != '' ) {
            $(response_messages).hide();
            user_posting(response_messages, response.msg);                    
            $("textarea[id='video_comment']").val('');
        } else {
            $(response_messages).hide();
            user_response(response_messages, '<?php echo $lang['587']; ?>');             
            $(".no_comments").hide();
            $("textarea[id='video_comment']").val('');
            var bDIV = $("#comments_delimiter");
            var cDIV = document.createElement("div");
            $(cDIV).html(response.code);
            $(bDIV).after(cDIV);
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

On video_comment.php, this is the response.code to show up the comment live on video page.

```
echo 'text...

echo '<div id="commentplayer"></div>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'jwplayer("commentplayer").setup({';
echo 'file: "...url",';  
echo 'width: "300",';
echo 'height: "225",';
echo 'provider: "http",';
echo 'startparam: "start",';
echo 'wmode: "transparent",';        
echo 'controls: "true",'; 
echo 'stretching: "uniform",';    
echo 'primary: "flash",';       
echo 'autostart: "false",';
echo 'ga: {}';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';

echo 'text...
```

I have no problem to get 'text...', but i can't get '<script type="text/javascript">function...</script>' to show up live on video page.

Help please...

Comment: Shouldn't `$(#comment)` be `$('#comment')`?

Comment: If you want to fetch the script and make it run you have to use $.getScript() http://api.jquery.com/getScript/

Comment: @Joseph Silber nope, that's not a problem. I forgot to quote here. :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not true at all. You don't **have** to use that in order for script to run. The response has normal text and also some script...this is a totally different situation. As soon as the Javascript is put on the page (with the `html` method), it's run.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard The link is broken. :(

Comment: How do you know the script doesn't run?  What **exactly** is in that `<script>` block?

Comment: Just wondering, but why are you escaping the `/` characters in the response?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed)

Comment: @Pointy It's exactly jw player embed code.

Comment: Here is the link - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ I forgot the doc site just changed.

Comment: `response.code` is `undefined`. Try using just `response`, and read that duplicate question...

Comment: @Ian Yes, i tried: '<script type=/"text\/javascript/">';

Comment: You say the response from the server is JSON, but the `echo` part in your PHP script does not look like to be JSON. The code you posted is very confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling Can't believe I didn't see that. I bet that's the problem

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it's JSON, i just removed others to shorten the jquery here. Actually, i believe that's not the problem on my jquery code because i can get other text... in response.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, you have to create JSON *on the server*. `echo "<script>...</script>";` certainly does not output JSON, but partial HTML. Which is fine as well, but then don't tell jQuery to expect JSON, and `response` would be a string containing HTML. Strings don't have a `code` property (I wonder why you think it should exist).

Comment: @richard Sorry, what I meant is that there is no need to escape the `/` characters. So I'd use something like `echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; echo '</script>';`. Notice how there aren't `\` characters before the `/`. I mean, I doubt this would be the problem, I was just pointing out that I don't think it's necessary

Comment: @Ian I just tried your suggestion, still same. it can response the text.. but javascript.

Comment: @richard if the stuff in the `<script>` that you return is just a function declaration, what is it that you expect to happen?  Have you used browser tools to determine whether the response really looks like what you expect it to look like?

Comment: @richard Okay, just wanted to make sure. So can you explain why you're saying it's JSON when it's clearly HTML/text that you return from PHP?

Comment: @ Guys, i've updated the javascript in my question. It's a jw player embed code.

Comment: @richard Your response contains **no** JSON. It contains HTML - text and HTML tags (`<script>`). There's no need to specify "JSON" for the last parameter of the `$.post` call.

Comment: @Ian I just tried but the script doesn't work after remove JSON.

Comment: @richard Your logic inside the callback makes no sense! You are returning **html**, yet you look at `response.msg` and see if it's `!= ''`. `response` is the text representation of the response, so it doesn't have a `.msg` attribute. I'm just wondering - where you think you're using JSON that you can use `response.msg` and `response_messages`?

Comment: @lan The response.msg is error/success message. e.g.: echo '{"status":0,"msg":"';
 echo '0 return error message';
 echo '"}'; if "status":1 then response above codes.

Comment: @richard I see, I see. I didn't realize you weren't posting the full response...just response.code. I guess it wouldn't matter anyways, as you were really only having trouble with the `<script>` part, since you could get the text to show fine

Comment: @lan, yes, that's weird part. Just can't show up the <script> part. I've tried replace a simple function inside <script type="text/javascript"></script> but still not show up the <script> part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of placing javascript code in the php return, why dont you place it in the `.post` response?

```
$("input[id*='post_video_comment']").click(function() {           
$.post('video_comment.php', function(response) {
  $('#comment').html(response.code);  
    //place javascript code here
}, "json");
```

});

or placing a `onload` before your `js` code

```
$str = '<div id="commentplayer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=(function() {
    jwplayer("commentplayer").setup({
    file: "...url",
    width: "300",
    height: "225",
    provider: "http",
    startparam: "start",
    wmode: "transparent",      
    controls: "true", 
    stretching: "uniform",  
    primary: "flash",     
    autostart: "false",
    ga: {}
    });
});
</script>';

echo $str;
```

Comment: I can't place the javascript code in post response, because the javascript function is display within a text. e.g: text... javascript ...text...

Comment: @richard i see, can you share the `js` inside the php then?  do you have a `onLoad` call?

Comment: @ tq, i've updated the javascript in my question. It's a jw player.

Comment: I just tried your onload solution, but the problem is, it's just show up "text...<div id="commentplayer"></div> text...", everything inside <script type="text/javascript"></script> missing.

Comment: right now it looks like you have `response.msg` which means that the response is looking for `msg`, can you use just `response`?

Comment: Tried response instead of response.msg, <script> still missing.

Comment: does this look familiar? http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/SOLVED-Shadowbox-JW-Player-x-JQuery-AJAX-BROKEN-td3759331.html

Comment: Nope, it's not related with it. My problem is <script> missing in ajax response.

Comment: can you try a differnt `<script>` maybe something simple and see if that runs?  if so then maybe `jwplayer` needs to be re examined

Comment: Yes, i've tried running a simple script before. it's same, everything missing inside <script>.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23157/discussion-between-t-q-and-richard)