# Yii ajaxLink jquery on view is not working

Tags: jquery, tabs, yii, datatable

On my page i have a tab view of three pages.For this am using CHtml::ajaxLink as below

```
<li >
                  <?php  echo CHtml::ajaxLink("Manual Billing", CController::createUrl('billing/manualbilling'), array('update' => 'html',
                                'type' => 'POST',));?>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <?php  echo CHtml::ajaxLink("Billing History", CController::createUrl('billing/historyBilling'), array('update' => 'html',
                                'type' => 'POST',

                                      ));?>
                </li>
                <li>
                       <?php  echo CHtml::ajaxLink("Merchant Wise Billing Status", CController::createUrl('billing/manualbilling'), array('update' => 'html',
                                'type' => 'POST'), array(//htmlOptions
                              //  'class' => "reportlink"
                            ));?>
                </li>
```

As given url the pages are loading but problem is i had given some jQuery function inside the view page for implementing datatable which is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sScrollY": "400px",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "oLanguage": {

                "sEmptyTable": "No records to display"
            },

            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "aaSorting": [],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "bSortable": false },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
            ],
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/media/js/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",                                      
                "aButtons": [
                    {
                        "sExtends": "print",
                        "sInfo": "Please press escape when print is completed."
                    }

                    //                                                 {
                    //                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    //                   // "sButtonText": "Save",
                    //                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                    //                }
                ]
            }

        } );

    } );
```

Its not even entering on document.ready().Please help

Comment: You did not tell how you integrate the javascript. Did you use `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript()`?

Comment: You should take a look at the CJuiTabs widget for setting up your tabs. (Not a solution to your problem though)   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiTabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Kevin Higgins issue resolved using CJuiTabs widget

```
$tabs = array(); 

                $tabs['Manual Billing'] = array( 
                        'id'=>'dataFieldsTab', 
                        'class'=>'bill',
                        'content'=>$this->renderPartial('manualbilling',$paramsm,true), 
                ); 

                $tabs['Billing History'] = array( 
                        'id'=>'linkedChildrenTab1', 
                        'class'=>'bill',

                        'content'=>$this->renderPartial('historyBilling',$paramsh,true), 
                ); 


                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(  
                        'tabs' => $tabs, 
                        'options' => array( 
                                'collapsible' => false, 
                                'active' => 0,
                        ), 
                ));
```

Thanks every one for help

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from how jQuery ajax calls handle strip tags.

Take a look at this article for a fix:
[jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed)