# Replacing script tag with cdata tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace `<script` with `<![CDATA[<script` , `</script>` with `</script>]]>` and put this into a new dom element.

So i wrote a regular expression to that replace the tags and i need to put this script as inner html to an element like as below

I wrote below code

```
  var html = "<script src=\"https://dynamic.test.com/test/test/common/js/test.js\"></script>";
  html = html.replace(/<script/ig,"<!CDATA[<script")
             .replace(/<\/script>/ig,"</script>]]>");


 console.log(""$j("<test/>").html(html)[0].outerHTML);
```

I am getting output as below

```
 <test><!--CDATA[<script src="https://dynamic.test.com/test/test/common/js/test.js"-->]]&gt;</test>
```

But the expected output is

```
    <test><!--CDATA[<script src="https://dynamic.test.com/test/test/common/js/test.js"></script>]]></test>
```

Comment: Why would you want do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Comment: I want to retain the <script> tag from jQuery html() contents. So i am adding cdata tag around it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your document is in HTML mode (i.e. served as `text/html`). HTML does not support explicit CDATA sections. You would need an XML document.

Use entities instead. Replace `<`, `>`, et al with `&lt;`, `&gt;` etc.

Better yet: Stop munging strings to create HTML. Use `appendChild` and `createTextNode`.

Comment: Is there any way to escape the html content from html parser other than commenting(<!-- .--> )

Comment: What does commenting have to do with CDATA sections?

Comment: I need to escape the <script> contents from html parser while calling jquery html(). i guess escaping can be done from parser by wrapping the contents with CDATA tag .

Comment: What do you mean by "escape"? describe your problem in plain English terms of what you want to happen to the script.