# Injecting HTML that contains JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've been given some great tips on how to inject HTML into HTML that I can't edit.

The trouble is now that the snippet contains JS it won't render to the page.

The Jquery looks lke this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {   
            var $body = $(document.body);   
              if ($body.is(".ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB")) {
            $('.info_section').prepend('<div id="test-widget"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/latest/build.min.js"  data-test="test-widget" data-instance="xyz" data-apikey="12345678" data-tags="" async="async"></script>');
        }
        });
```

I tried putting backslashes in before the quotations but this didn't work.

How else can you write this to the page so that the JS is included?

Many thanks,

Adam

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fs6qgzrj/

Comment: Can you please provide a full example.. as in the page your putting this in to. Ideally a jsFiddle so we can work with your example. You would be better of creating a new script tag instead of using prepend..

Comment: You should probably load your script from your js code instead of injecting html to load it.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rg7c3sr2/ this seems to work

Comment: the fiddle here is using a inline script, having one with src would fail. But still proves point can be done depending on the need

Comment: Added JS fiddle -thanks

Comment: Your fiddle is reporting a syntax error in the JS console. Also, the URL of the `.js` file is incorrect -- it doesn't have a hostname, so it's looking for the script on the jsfiddle server.

Comment: You also didn't have jQuery selected in the Framework menu.

Comment: I've confirmed that it doesn't load an external JS file: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fs6qgzrj/5/

Answer (score 2):

This is a security feature. jQuery allows `<script>` elements in HTML code but it won't execute them (at least not the `src="..."` part; inline scripts work). This is because jQuery has no way to make sure the script isn't malicious or from a safe source (an error in your code might allow people to enter scripts in a form element).

Use `jQuery.getScript(url, successCallack)` instead.

See also: [jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed?lq=1)

Comment: I just tried `$('body').append('<script>alert("foo");</script>')` in the Javascript console and it alerted.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. I think you refer to `.html()` in particular, that won't execute the script while `.append()` does: https://jsfiddle.net/rg7c3sr2/

Comment: @BeNdErR All the jQuery methods that insert DOM elements eventually flow into the same code.

Comment: What doesn't work is loading an external JS file. It only works with inline HTML.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I was worried about. The widget I'm trying to inject on the page is an external JS

Comment: @Barmer: I updated my answer to make it clear that the `src` attribute is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery won't load an external script when parsing HTML. But if you create a script element it will:

```js
$('body').prepend($('<script>', {
  src: 'http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test.js'
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```