# Load/Append multiple contents together with $('#id').html(contents) failing to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Load content is failing with jQuery $('#id').html() when I try to load below contents in Chrome/Edge. Same is working in IE11
Working on IE11 to Chrome/Edge migration

Issue - Style and div contents were loading with .html() but when it encounters JavaScript block, it fails to load. Unable to find respective functions further

Contents structure is

```
    var contents = "<style>
   #tags{
  float:left;
}
#tags input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
}
</style>
<div id="divDD">
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
<div id="divTemplateSC">
    <!-- contents -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // contains variable declarations and functions
    var Template;
    var Tags;
    (function ($, window, document) {
    
    }(window.jQuery, window, document));
    
    function GetTemplate()
    {
        // Function call to get template
        // Assign data to Template
    }
    
    function GetTags()
    {
        // Function call to get Tags
        // Assign data to Tag
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").change(function () {
            onContentChange();
        });
    });
    
    // further functions continues...
</script>";

$('#id').html(contents);
```

Comment: you loaded `jquery.min.js` cdn??

Comment: share the code where you're adding data into `contents` variable. Also, what is the problem here? "it fails to load" is very vague.

Comment: @HymnZzy, content object contains Style, HTML and Scripts returned from the service as one data(as mentioned above). When it bind with .html(contents) only style and html contents will bind to the #id tag and unable to bind script contents

Comment: Are you saying the functions aren't working or the `script` tag isn't being populated? If it is the latter then you have a mismatch in closing the tags. Look into your browser console and see if you have any errors.

Comment: @KUMAR, not from CDN

Comment: @HymnZzy, script block not loading basically. Due to which functions were not present to call. Verified in browser console, no mismatch of tags as well. Same is working in IE11

Comment: After .html() I can able to see style and html contents in inspect element. There were loaded properly but scripts were not present

Comment: IE11 is not a benchmark you should be looking at anymore. Unless you can share the content inside `script` tag it'll be impossible to debug it. You can `$('#id').append(contents)` instead of `$('#id').html(contents)` and see if it works for your case

Comment: Tried with $('#id').append(contents) as well. Further tried to split the script and html blocks and bind html with $('#id').html(<html>) and script with $('#id').append(script_contents). still unable to load. Sure, updating the sample contents inside it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed)