# What event gets fired after a script type of module gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules, script-tag

I am loading a page via ajax. Included in that page, there's a `<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>` element.

What event gets fired after a script type of module gets loaded in this way?

Comment: Should be just the normal ones for `<script>` elements. Did you try them?

Comment: The problem is that module type scripts are loaded in parallel. When an ajax request completes, it is only for the requested page/html fragment, and the script could still be loading at that point

Comment: "*I am loading a page via ajax*" - how exactly are you doing that? Notice that AJAX only loads the html string, it doesn't load anything referenced from that.

Comment: `it doesn't load anything referenced from that.` - yes it does. You can add a `<script>` in that html string and that script will be loaded as well.

Comment: Not if you only use ajax (`XMLHttpRequest`). What exactly are you doing? Please show us your code.

Comment: `$.get('/html-with-script-tag', (data)=>container.html(data));`

Comment: Ah, you should've stated that you're using jQuery. [jQuery treats `<script>` tags in its `.html()` method weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2699320/1048572), and only adding them to the html does cause them to be loaded.

Comment: Yep the script tag is being loaded. I have no problem with that. My question is if there's an event that gets fired in the case I presented above that I can hook on to.

Comment: Yes, it does fire the events, but still I don't think they're any different for `type="module"` than for normal scripts.

Comment: `type="module"` only fires the first time it gets loaded, regular scripts fire every time is gets loaded

Comment: Why would it get loaded multiple times? It also doesn't run multiple times.

Comment: The project I am working on loads the page (html fragment) and it includes the script tag. For example, if I load page1 html via ajax, there's a corresponding page1.js script tag included. If I load page2, page2.js is included. These scripts handles UI events, etc. Now, if I go back to page1, page1.js should then load again to handle UI events, but this doesn't happen with `type=module`. It only runs once.

Comment: Yes, that's how modules are supposed to work. If you need to run the code that attaches UI event handlers multiple times, don't put it into a script - put it into a function instead and just call that when you have loaded the html fragment.

Comment: "don't put it into a script" - you're saying bundle it in one script. That's what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to load the script as needed. Load it only after the ajax call. I have a solution to this but I'm looking for something better.

Comment: No, by "script" I was referring to code that executes stuff at the top-level. You cannot and should not run such a script as a module. If you want to use modules (and you should), put the code into a function that you can call.

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing. The page event handlers are in a function onMount() exported by the module (ex. page1.js), but of course, as I've explained, I want to load that script on demand via ajax (not bundled). The onMount() is called when the script type module is loaded, but since script type modules are loaded only once, the onMount() will not be called again when I go back to the page. Again, I have a workaround, but am looking for a better one, hence my question above.

Comment: Don't use a module for the code that calls `onMount`. Use a script that does `import(…).then(onMount => onMount())`. This you can execute arbitrarily often.

Comment: That's it! Not exactly an event, but that works. Problem now is that I need to use node modules, which I don't think would work with ES modules (possible to a point, but problematic with other module dependencies). Anyway, thank you! TIL `import()`